# Calculate the sales share per country per day

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8f9d073878f7eca5084037857a0c2810)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    event_date DATE,
    country VARCHAR,
    sales DECIMAL
);

INSERT INTO sales
(event_date, country, sales)
VALUES 
('2020-02-08', 'DE', '500'),
('2020-02-08', 'FR', '900'),
('2020-02-08', 'NL', '700'),
('2020-03-20', 'US', '600'),
('2020-03-20', 'DE', '500'),
('2020-04-15', 'NL', '300'),
('2020-04-15', 'FR', '800'),
('2020-04-15', 'NL', '100');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
event_date  |  country  |    sales_share_per_country_per_day    |
------------|-----------|---------------------------------------|-------------
2020-02-08  |    DE     |     0.24  (=500/2100)                 |  
2020-02-08  |    FR     |     0.43  (=900/2100)                 |
2020-02-08  |    NL     |     0.33  (=700/2100)                 |
------------|-----------|---------------------------------------|-------------
2020-03-20  |    US     |     0.55  (=600/1100)                 |
2020-03-20  |    DE     |     0.45  (=500/1100)                 |
------------|-----------|---------------------------------------|-------------
2020-04-15  |    NL     |     0.25  (=300/1200)                 |
2020-04-15  |    FR     |     0.67  (=800/1200)                 |
2020-04-15  |    NL     |     0.08  (=100/1100)                 |
```

---

I want to calculate the **sales share per country per day**. 
Therefore, I tried to go with this query:

```
SELECT
s.event_date,
s.country,
s.sales,
SUM(s.sales) OVER (PARTITION BY s.country) AS sales_share_per_day
FROM sales s
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 1;
```

However, I could not achieve the expected result. 
Do you have any idea how I have to modify the query?

---

*NOTE: In the end I will need this query for redshift. 

However, as far as I know for window functions redshift uses postgresSQL syntax. 

Therefore I tagged redshift and postgresSQL in the question. 

Feel free to correct me if this assumption is wrong.*

Comment: . . This is very similar to previous questions you have asked.  What do you need here that is different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**With sales_share_per_day rounding off to two digits after decimal point**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE sales (
>     id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
>     event_date DATE,
>     country VARCHAR,
>     sales DECIMAL
> );
>
> INSERT INTO sales
> (event_date, country, sales)
> VALUES 
> ('2020-02-08', 'DE', '500'),
> ('2020-02-08', 'FR', '900'),
> ('2020-02-08', 'NL', '700'),
> ('2020-03-20', 'US', '600'),
> ('2020-03-20', 'DE', '500'),
> ('2020-04-15', 'NL', '300'),
> ('2020-04-15', 'FR', '800'),
> ('2020-04-15', 'NL', '100');
> ```

> ```
>         SELECT
>         s.event_date,
>         s.country,
>         s.sales,
>         round(s.sales/sum(s.sales) OVER (PARTITION BY event_date ),2) AS sales_share_per_day
>         FROM sales s
>         ORDER BY 1;
> ```

> | event_date | country | sales | sales_share_per_day |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2020-02-08 | DE | 500 | 0.24 |
> | 2020-02-08 | FR | 900 | 0.43 |
> | 2020-02-08 | NL | 700 | 0.33 |
> | 2020-03-20 | US | 600 | 0.55 |
> | 2020-03-20 | DE | 500 | 0.45 |
> | 2020-04-15 | NL | 300 | 0.25 |
> | 2020-04-15 | FR | 800 | 0.67 |
> | 2020-04-15 | NL | 100 | 0.08 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=94769d4d1b532d29e6bb52e0d2b9e517)*

**Without rounding off:**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE sales (
>     id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
>     event_date DATE,
>     country VARCHAR,
>     sales DECIMAL
> );
>
> INSERT INTO sales
> (event_date, country, sales)
> VALUES 
> ('2020-02-08', 'DE', '500'),
> ('2020-02-08', 'FR', '900'),
> ('2020-02-08', 'NL', '700'),
> ('2020-03-20', 'US', '600'),
> ('2020-03-20', 'DE', '500'),
> ('2020-04-15', 'NL', '300'),
> ('2020-04-15', 'FR', '800'),
> ('2020-04-15', 'NL', '100');
> ```

> ```
>         SELECT
>         s.event_date,
>         s.country,
>         s.sales,
>         s.sales/sum(s.sales) OVER (PARTITION BY event_date ) AS sales_share_per_day
>         FROM sales s
>         ORDER BY 1;
> ```

> | event_date | country | sales | sales_share_per_day |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2020-02-08 | DE | 500 | 0.23809523809523809524 |
> | 2020-02-08 | FR | 900 | 0.42857142857142857143 |
> | 2020-02-08 | NL | 700 | 0.33333333333333333333 |
> | 2020-03-20 | US | 600 | 0.54545454545454545455 |
> | 2020-03-20 | DE | 500 | 0.45454545454545454545 |
> | 2020-04-15 | NL | 300 | 0.25000000000000000000 |
> | 2020-04-15 | FR | 800 | 0.66666666666666666667 |
> | 2020-04-15 | NL | 100 | 0.08333333333333333333 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a0e2bd7d44122000c9851d89df02795b)*

Comment: Just for my own documentation: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d229f4911dc4ecd83c02b213355e6cef

Comment: If you want you can round it to .24 or .43 etc. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

Was it this that you were after?

```
SELECT
s.event_date,
s.country,
s.sales,
(
   s.sales 
 / SUM(s.sales) OVER(PARTITION BY event_date)
)::NUMERIC(9,2) AS sales_pct_per_day,
SUM(s.sales) OVER(PARTITION BY event_date) AS sales_share_per_day
FROM sales s
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 1;
event_date  country sales   sales_pct_per_day   sales_share_per_day
2020-02-08  DE      500         0.24                2100
2020-02-08  FR      900         0.43                2100
2020-02-08  NL      700         0.33                2100
2020-03-20  US      600         0.55                1100
2020-03-20  DE      500         0.45                1100
2020-04-15  FR      800         0.67                1200
2020-04-15  NL      300         0.25                1200
2020-04-15  NL      100         0.08                1200
```